# Simple meanings of row vectors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A linear map from $F^n$ to $F^m$ can be represented by an $m\times n$ matrix. The meaning of the column vectors are simple and clear. They are the images of the standard basis vectors of $F^n$. What about the row vectors? Is there a similar simple interpretation of their meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interpret the row vectors as images of the standard dual basis under the transpose operator.

If $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is your basis, you define the dual base in $(F^n)^*=\{f:F^n\to F\text{ linear}\}$ by $e_n^*(e_k)=\delta_{kn}$. Then the transpose of an operator $T\colon F^n\to F^m$ is defined by $T^*\colon (F^m)^*\to (F^n)^*$ mapping $T^*(f)=f\circ T$. The operator $T^*$ can be written as $\text{Mat}(T)^t$ in the basis $e_i^*$, where $\text{Mat}(T)^t$ is the transposed matrix, which has the $i$-th row of $\text{Mat}(T)$ as its $i$-th column and vice-versa. Thus if the matrix corresponding to $T$ had the form $T e_k=\sum_{i=1}^m t_{ki}e_i$, then we would have $T^*e_k^*=\sum_{i=1}^n t_{ik}e_i^*$.

Comment: Can we simply interpret the row vectors as $m$ dual vectors of $F^n$? What I mean is this. The $n$ column vectors are the $n$ vectors in $F^m$ which are the images of the $n$ standard basis of $F^n$, which of course determines $T$ uniquely. Similarly, $T$ is uniquely determined by $m$ dual vectors by $T(v)=(f_1(v), f_2(v), f_3(v), ..., f_m(v))$. And the $m$ dual vectors $f_i$ are the $m$ row vectors.

Comment: That is more I less what I tried to tell you. You can interpret the row vectors as the image of the dual basis vectors under the transposed map $T^*$ expressed in the dual basis.

Comment: OK. Let say the kernel of $T$ is $K$. Now if you interpret the $m$ row vectors as $m$ dual vectors, then they are in the annililator of the $K$, $K^\perp$. How can I show that they span $K^\perp$?

Comment: OK. Let say the kernel of $T$ is $K$. Now if I interpret the $m$ row vectors as $m$ dual vectors, then they are in the annililator of the $K$, $K^\perp$. How can I show that they span $K^\perp$? I want to interpret the $m$ row vectors as dual vectors that span the annililator of the kernel of $T$.

Comment: In finite dimensional vector spaces it generally holds that $Im(T^*)=Ker(T)^\perp$. To see this, note that $x\in (Im(T^*))^\perp$ if and only if $(T^*f)(x)=0$ for all $f$ if and only if $f(Tx)=0$ for all $f$ if and only if $x\in Ker(T)$.